# Creating new Signer throws XadesProfileResolutionException [Android Xades4j]

Tags: android, exception, xades4j, signer

I have simple method getSigner which return new Signer (XadesSigner object).
The same method works on simple console java application but in Android throws XadesProfileResolutiionException.
Anyone help me?

```
private XadesSigner getSigner(String pfxPath, String password) throws SigningKeyException {

    try {
        KeyingDataProvider keyingProvider = getKeyingDataProvider(pfxPath, password);
        XadesSigningProfile p = new XadesBesSigningProfile(keyingProvider);
        return p.newSigner();

    } catch (KeyStoreException ex) {
        throw new SigningKeyException("Keystore Problem", ex);
    } catch (SigningCertChainException ex) {
        throw new SigningKeyException("Signer Cert Chain Problem", ex);
    } catch (UnexpectedJCAException ex) {
        throw new SigningKeyException("JCA Problem", ex);
    } catch (XadesProfileResolutionException ex) {
        throw new SigningKeyException("XadesProfileResolutionException Problem", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the details of the (inner) exception?

Comment: @Igoncalves I took cause of exception and i got "xades4j.utils.XadesProfileResolutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"

Comment: @Igoncalves Caused by: xades4j.utils.XadesProfileResolutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at xades4j.utils.XadesProfileCore.getInstance(XadesProfileCore.java:223 at xades4j.production.XadesSigningProfile.newSigner(XadesSigningProfile.java:112) at pl.ezla.mobile.business.podpis.EPodpisOswiadczenieBusiness.getSigner

Comment: There's no message in any of those? It could be something with Guice usage. The library was never really tested in Android..

Comment: @Igoncalves here is whole error -> https://pastebin.com/DXPG91DV

Comment: I have no clue what it is. The root cause seems to be

"java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: can't load this type of class file at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:594)"

I don't know enough of Java or Android to be able to tell what the problem may be. Can try to dig a bit more though..

Comment: @treekt can you provide a sample Android project replicating this issue?

Comment: That would be good. We can create an issue in GH to try to troubleshoot this further and discuss any outcome.
(Thanks @jzeferino)

Comment: Ok guys I have created simple android project. First choose document xml, next choose certificate and type password. And last step - click sign button... If password is okey and you selected every files then app throw away the XadesProfileResolutionException. And remember about permissions in Android Settings App because in another case app throw UnexpectedJCAException. Link: https://github.com/treekt/xadesSigning

Comment: https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/issues/154

Comment: Did you resolve that issue guys ?